# Android Layout for Tablets

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen

I am trying to make my app work for all devices, but I am having trouble doing so. How can I get rid of this gap?[image]

Here is what it is supposed to look like:
[image]

It works fine on my phone ,but not on this tablet emulator. What techniques can I use to fix this? I have read supporting multiple screen sizes, but I can't make much of it.
Here is the code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/terranlogo1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_below="@id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_below="@id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/terranlogo2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ck_t1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/terranlogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/protosslogo2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ck_p1"
    android:src="@drawable/protosslogo" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/zerglogo2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ck_z1"
    android:src="@drawable/zerglogo" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_t2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/terranlogo2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_p2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/protosslogo1"
    android:layout_below="@id/protosslogo2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_below="@id/zerglogo2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_gametime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_mistakenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ck_t2"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Choose your opponets race(s) and your race(s)"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/s_gametime"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Answer Time"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Mistakes \nAllowed"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/s_gametime"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Game Length"
    android:textSize="15dp" />
```

Comment: It would help to have a picture of how it looks on the phone - when it is correct! I see you are using dp which is the correct way to fit it - on tablets forcing landscape might look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the attribute `android:layout_below="@id/textview4` to s_answertime. You might have to move textview4 so it is above s_answertime:

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ck_z2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/zerglogo1"
    android:layout_below="@id/zerglogo2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ck_t2"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Choose your opponets race(s) and your race(s)"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/s_answertime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/textview4 />\
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I do that for all spinner? It crashes if I do more than one.

Comment: Should only have to do one and than put android:layout_toRightOf="s_answertime" for the rest of the spinners. Give it a shot

Comment: Also, take out android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for all the spinners.

Comment: I my answer answered your question, others could benefit by you accepting it.

Comment: I know get this: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_toRightOf' with value 
 's_answertime').

Comment: Make sure you put @id\ in front of s_answer time.

Comment: Correction: android:layout_toRightOf="@id/s_answertime".

Answer (score 0):

How about simply make another layout?

Put XML file with same name to "layout-xlarge" folder, or if you need to have it in ONE file, try LinearLayout with weight attribute (layout_width/height = 0dp) to expand your view elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
        android:layout_below="@id/textview4 />\
                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 






        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Spinner"
        />
```